# Javascript regex to extract in brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, html

I am working with some html that is created at runtime, where I need to get text using regex in Javascript. The html has an edit box that contains some text, and an image tag that looks like this:

```
<img src="http://server/directory/subdirectory/Images1/logo_aa.png" alt=" logo_ce" data-tag=" [[image: logo_aa]] ">
```

I need to be able to extract the "[[image: logo_aa]]" portion out, and then replace the whole html image tag with it. But or some reason, regex only gets "a]" when I run it. Here is an example of the code that I am using:

```
var imgHtmlPattern = new RegExp("<img[^>]*?>", "g");
var imageTagPattern = new RegExp("\[\[Image:\s\S+\]\]", "i");

var str = 'A whole paragraph of text here. <img src="http://server/directory/subdirectory/Images1/logo_aa.png" alt=" logo_ce" data-tag=" [[image: logo_aa]] ">';

var matches = str.match(imgHtmlPattern);

for (i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {

    var test = imageTagPattern.exec(matches[i]);
    alert(test);

    //  var tag = matches[i].match(imageTagPattern);
    //  alert(tag);
}
```

var imageTagPattern = new RegExp("[[Image:\s\S+]]", "i");

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/haFGm1wbs505Srya)

Comment: [regex101.com is great for testing your regular expressions](https://regex101.com/r/eD2yV3/1)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/30t26f1c/

Comment: That is a great site. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use double `\\` for `RegExp` object creation:

```
var imageTagPattern = new RegExp("\\[\\[Image:\\s\\S+\\]\\]", "i");
```

Or just use regex literal:

```
var imageTagPattern = /\[\[Image:\s\S+\]\]/i;
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. Thanks for the very prompt reply.